# send Wordpress polylang language code to Angular Applications

Tags: angular, wordpress, typescript

I am trying to control the language of Angular application in wordpress via wordpress polylang.

For this I have created the following structure in my Angular application:

getLanguage.php

```
<?php
require_once("../../../../../wp-load.php");
$data = get_bloginfo("language");
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

http.service.ts

```
getLanguage(): any {
   return this.http.get(environment.url)
}
```

app.component.ts

```
this.http.getLanguage().subscribe( res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.lang = res;
    });
```

Response is
de-DE or fr-FR

This works fine.
However, when I change the language from my wordpress website to french and switch to the angular application, the LanguageCode stays at its default value of the german language de-DE.

My angular application is inside the wordpress theme and is called via wordpress page-app.php.

Is there any other way to send the language from wordpress polylang to the angular app or am I missing something here

Answer (score 1):

it was this simple.

i had to translate the wordpress page page-app.php

so i have page-app.php for german
page-app-fr.php for french